# Windows 10 lock screen slideshow options greyed out

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen

I am trying to set my lock screen to a slideshow on Windows 10, but the options are greyed out. How can I enable these options?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 (use winver to determine this).  Are you connected to a domain?

Comment: @Ramhound http://i.imgur.com/mRJcb92.png. It is connected to a domain, but I'm not sure if these are controlled by group policy. I sort of expected to see a "Some settings are controlled by your organization" message if that were the case. Maybe I'm wrong about that.

Comment: You are not sure if it is controlled by a group policy.  You should ask your Domain Administrator If the setting is controlled by a group policy. If you are not an administrator on the domain we cannot help you change it.

Comment: Okay, I checked and there is not a GPO disabling this.

Comment: Are you using any sort of profile redirection by chance?  Are you using roaming profiles by chance?

Comment: Hmm. I think this might be group policy after all. I was told that "Prevent enabling lock screen slide show" was not set, and it's not. However "Force specific screen saver" is set. On a local account I tried enabling "Force specific screen saver" in local GP, and it seems to disable the lock screen slideshow as well. Not what I expected, but I think this might be the problem.

Comment: It is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the group policy "Force specific screen saver" will disable the lock screen slide show options. This is despite the fact that there is a separate GPO called "Prevent enabling lock screen slide show." I am not entirely sure why you can't set a specific screensaver while also having a lock screen slideshow.

Comment: If you can't set the screensaver to the slide show, you can't change it, some companies might want to provide the ability to set a static screensaver but not used a slide show of personal pictures hence the reason two separate policies exist

Comment: @Ramhound I guess what I don't understand is, why are they connected at all? I would expect to be able to enable a screensaver and a lockscreen slideshow at the same time, but apparently that is not possible. A side effect of that is that GP for screensavers affects the lockscreen settings, which doesn't really make sense.